# Passing data to server before page is rendered in node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, render

After a user logs in, the data is stored on a client side.

There are some pages which don't require a logged user to be viewed...

for example, I have a route on node.js which renders a profile page through a URL parameter.

```
app.get("Profile/:id",function(req,res){ //render page and send it.}
```

anyone can see this page... but here is the situation... in my app, users can post notes on these pages so they can see it later. So the idea is, if a user is logged in when the user accesses that page they can see all their notes.

the data of the notes are in server side.

So my question is...
How can I pass the user data into app.get("profile/:id "... function so that the notes can be loaded and sent when is rendered...

one thing is important to be known. I have a solution in which I pass a unique key though the URL which references to the active socket of the user so that the data is posted on a JSON, is there any other way to pass data from client to server before the page is rendered?

Comment: How your authentication/authorization works? JWT or something else?

Comment: or *express-sessions* ?

Comment: So, are you saying your solution allows a user to send a link to their friend, and that friend automatically appears logged in as the first person just because they navigate using the link with the URL-encoded key? That's really unsafe.

Comment: i dont get it, for autentification i encript password in client side and post it through the client socket, and later decripted on server side...  but what does that have to do with the problem?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts the key is terminated after the data is sent. After that, no one can enter as logged.

Comment: But your observation is true, it's just a raw solution, I ask, to see if there is a correct way to achieve this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After several days I have manage to achieve the resolution of this question

The idea is to have a Session tipe variable like $_SESSION in php.

you need express-session npm and assign session on require parameter on a express post function. After you have set a value, every time that browser change from location, you can extract that same session variable and use the data to post a response when you are rendering.

I used ejs to render.

In the next link, there is a full tutorial to achieve this.

https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Thank, didn't know this